# OpenSSL BIO_get_fd() returns -1 unless called after BIO_do_connect()

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

I am using the Openssl Bio API to start an SSL connection:

```
SSL* ssl{nullptr};
SSL_CTX* ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());
BIO* bio = BIO_new_ssl_connect(ctx);

BIO_get_ssl(bio, &ssl);
SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(ssl, host);

BIO_set_conn_hostname(bio, host_and_port);
     
int res = BIO_do_connect(bio);
```

This has worked fine.

Now I want to set the socket to use a specific Linux interface using `setsockopt()` with `SO_BINDTODEVICE`.

To get the raw socket file desciptor I use `BIO_get_fd()`:

```
int sock = -1;
BIO_get_fd(bio, &sock);

setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, interface_name, strlen(interface_name));

// Here sock = -1
BIO_do_connect(bio);
// Here sock > 0
```

The problem is the socket file descriptor is invalid if called before `BIO_do_connect()`. The file descriptor is valid after `BIO_do_connect()`
but surely I need to set the interface before openssl calls `::connect()`?

Is it still possible to set the socket to use the interface?

Comment: Create and bind the socket outside of openssl, then use BIO_set_fd to assign it to the BIO.